# Блочный курсор в редакторе кода Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Я понимаю, что хочу странного, и м.б. плохо искал, но ... хотелось бы в Visual Studio 2019 (OS Windows 10) сделать блочный курсор, а-ля из консоли linux или notepad++. Не подскажете решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlockCaret можете попробовать. Расширение для vs2019

Comment: Да, интересное расширение, спасибо! Оно еще курсор не прячет, так что если видно несколько текстовых окон, курсор виден во всех вкладках/окнах.